# Whats are the Protractor Supported versions of Firefox, IE and Safari?

Tags: protractor

Whats are the Protractor Supported versions of Firefox, IE and Safari?

My test does not run in Firefox latest version.

Comment: What Protractor version are you using?

Comment: Protractor version - 5.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@High level Protractor is just a wrapper around webdriver. It depends on browser versions you want to test en the webdrivers for that browsers you have downloaded with `webdriver-manager` as said by @alecxe.

Currently there are some known issues with the webdrivers that can also be found on the Protractor GitHub:

- **Firefox latest** has problems with Angular2 apps, see this [link](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/515#issuecomment-291208999), as far as I can remember Protractor worked till Firefox 47, it broke due to problems in de webdriver of Firefox from version 48-50 and it started working from 51, but not for Angular 2.
- **IE11** works
- **Microsoft Edge**, see [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2377#issuecomment-290836086), as far as I can see still not stable on version 14.
- **Safari 9**, works, but it's with the old Safari Driver, it misses a lot of user interactions like Tabs, mouse events and so on.
- **Safari 10**, I've heard that it works with the latest version of the Safari webdriver, don't heave experience with it, see also [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4169) for a guy who had problems with it but got it working.
- **Chrome**, should work with all latest versions if you always keep you ChromeDriver up-to-date.

Hope this gives you a good idea!

Comment: My App is Angular 1 and I am using all latest versions of webdrivers with Firefox 51, but still test are not running.

Comment: Then please provide more info like a config, script etc

Comment: Config : `capabilities : {
        'browserName' : 'firefox',
        'marionette' : 'false',
    },
    directConnect : true,`

Comment: Firefox version : 51, WebDriver version : v0.15.0 ,  selenium standalone version : 3.3.1       Firefox browser launches but it does not navigate to test url. I get following error : `[14:20:40] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[14:20:40] I/direct - Using FirefoxDriver directly...
[14:20:46] E/launcher - Unable to parse new session response: {"value": {"sessionId":"2b70fdad-8040-4304-a941-65de520f108e","value":{"XULappId":"{ec80
30f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","acceptSslCerts":false,"appBuildId":"20170125094131","browserName":"firefox","browserVersion":"51.0.1","command_id"`

Comment: `directConnect:true` could be the problem, see [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4182). It's "better" to use a standalone `webdriver-manager`. Do `npm install webdriver-manager -g`, then `webdriver-manager update`, then `webdriver-manager start`. It will run a local webdriver-manager. You can access it with by adding `seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'` to your config and remove `directConnect : true`.

Answer (score 1):

Protractor depends on the [`webdriver-manager` package](https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/blob/12.0.4/CHANGELOG.md#1200) which now, since version `12.0.0`, installs the latest versions of  `selenium-webdriver`, `iedriver`, `chromedriver` and `geckodriver`.

Then, to determine which browser versions are supported, you need to see what driver version was installed by the `webdriver-manager`:

```
$ webdriver-manager status
```

and then look up what browser versions your installed driver version supports.

---

> My test does not run in Firefox latest version.

In your case, you might be experiencing [this problem](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#webdriver-manager):

> Webdriver-manager will now by default grab the latest versions of all
>   binaries (standalone, chromedriver, iedriver, gecko driver). Use the
>   --versions.(binary name) to pin to a specific version. Selenium standalone 3.0.1 has a bug which prevents it from working with any
>   version of FireFox. We have tested version 3.0.0-beta4 and know that
>   it works with FireFox 51, and we expect that the 3.0.2 release will
>   also work.

Which currently means that you should be able to fix it by running:

```
$ webdriver-manager update
```

Or, you may also try the [`directConnect` mode](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/f9c8a37f7dbec1dccec2dde0bd6884ad7ae3f5c7/docs/server-setup.md#connecting-directly-to-browser-drivers).

Comment: I tried as you explained in the above solution, but still my test does not run on firefox and IE. I get following error on firefox :  `
[11:54:25] E/launcher - Unable to parse new session response:`

Comment: following are the versions of drivers: `C:\Users\ssharma\AppData\Roaming\npm>webdriver-manager status
[11:37:43] I/status - selenium standalone version available: 3.3.1 [last]
[11:37:43] I/status - chromedriver version available: 2.28 [last]
[11:37:43] I/status - geckodriver version available: v0.15.0 [last]
[11:37:43] I/status - IEDriverServer version available: 3.3.0 [last]
[11:37:43] I/status - android-sdk is not present
[11:37:43] I/status - appium is not present`