# Not able to run protractor tests in firefox

Tags: protractor

I'm having trouble running tests on firefox

```
firefox: {
        name: 'Firefox',
        browserName: 'firefox',
        logName: 'Firefox',
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 3
    },
 exports.config = {
      directConnect: true,
      firefoxPath: null,
```

Errors out with the following

```
[14:28:56] I/direct - Using FirefoxDriver directly...
[14:28:56] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[14:29:42] E/launcher - Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://127.0.0.1:51681/hub
[14:29:42] E/launcher - Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://127.0.0.1:51681/hub
    at Error (native)
    at onError (C:\QA\testingmaster\tests\protractor_tests\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\util.js:87:11)
```

Firefox browser starts but doesn't navigate to `baseUrl` instead it chokes on `about:blank&utm_content=firstrun` in the address bar

I have seen a couple of posts suggesting to start `selenium-server` manually. Is there a definite answer out there ?

Comment: Can you give some  more info like which version of Firefox you are using and if you are automating an Angular 1 or 2 app? Tnx in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43189784/whats-are-the-protractor-supported-versions-of-firefox-ie-and-safari

Comment: @wswebcreation Firefox 52 and angular1

Comment: @CodeJockey, can you give a complete version of you config file? It now looks like you are not using `capabilities:{}`. What you can also do it try to downgrade to Firefox version 47. Firefox 47 was the last stable version that could work with Protractor / Selenium.  48/51 were not stable. I don't got a reliable answer on the question if this a `directConnect: true` issue, but you could also try to use a standalone `webdriver-manager` just to check, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43194582/unable-to-parse-new-session-response-when-run-protractor-test-in-firefox/43198455#43198455)

Comment: @wswebcreation I'm using capabilities:{} and also I downgraded to firefox 47, but it outputs the following error when i run my test `Error: Error: The geckodriver.exe executable could not be found on the current PATH. Please download the latest version from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/WebDriver and ensure it can be found on your PATH.`

Answer (score 0):

Replace entire firefox: {} with just browserName: 'firefox'. i think this will solve the problem.

Comment: Nope, still the same result i.e. chokes on `about:blank&utm_content=firstrun` in the address bar